# Obfuscating Strings with ASCII and base 128

Tags: python, encoding, obfuscation, ascii

Suppose a string is a number system where each thing, it can be a char, DEL or any ASCII thing, has a corresponding number according to this ASCII [table](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii_table.jpg). How can you convert arbitrary string of the property to number in Python?

**An example**

```
#car = 35*128**3+99*128**2+97*128**1+114*128**0=75034866
```

Comment: Where are you getting those numbers from?

Comment: Falmari: from CHR -column to DEC, maybe easier way to do it

Comment: Calling this "encryption" is grossly misleading.

Comment: @HH: Encryption usually involves some sort of secret key. At a stretch you could call this "obfuscation" but I'd say it's just a simple form of encoding (not encryption).

Comment: Obfuscating data without using real encryption leads to a false sense of security.

Comment: @overstood: No, that's incorrect.  You're assuming that everyone who uses obfuscation believes it's a perfect security mechanism, which is silly.  Obfuscation is a meaningful *component* of many real-world security systems, and is very often implemented competently with a full understanding of its limitations.  Implementing *any* security mechanism without a competent understanding of its limitations leads to a false sense of security.

Comment: @glenn If your data is not encrypted, and someone has access to it they have your data. It doesn't matter if it's obfuscated or not. Additionally, obfuscating unencrypted data provides a false sense of security and often obfuscates the fact that one's data is insecure from oneself.

Comment: @overstood: No, they have your data *after they bypass the obfuscation*, which is generally the point.  No, it doesn't provide a "false sense of security", except to someone not competent to understand the limitations of security mechanisms.  Don't assume everyone is incompetent.

Comment: @glenn The point is that "bypassing obfuscation" is trivial. Obfuscation does not protect data! If you disagree, please obfuscate and post your credit card info (or some other sensitive data).

Comment: @overstood: No, it's not trivial when the obfuscation isn't trivial.  Bringing up "credit card numbers" makes it clear you don't understand the point, or have any experience with, the goals of commonplace obfuscation: not to prevent the copying and reverse engineering of data, but to delay it.

Comment: @glenn Maybe you could provide examples instead of resorting to an ad hominem. I agree that obfuscation can in SOME cases slow down the decoding of data. I just can't think of a real world case where someone has access sensitive data, and where merely slowing down the decoding of that data is ever a sufficient data protection strategy. If at any point you rely on obfuscation to protect data, you are setting yourself up for failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
total = 0
for c in "#car":
    total <<= 7
    total += ord(c)
print total
```

Result:

```
75034866
```

To get back the original string:

```
result = []
while total:
    result.append(chr(total % 128))
    total >>= 7
print ''.join(reversed(result))
```

Result:

```
#car
```

Comment: Nice, for the special case of base128

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrarily long numbers, use Decimal in Python 2.x and just int in Python 3.x.

No idea about 'encryption'.

Comment: Python ints get automatically promoted to Python longs. Python longs are arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to find a mapping to obfuscate the data.

Real encryption requires the use of a trap door function - a function that is computationally easy to compute one way, but the inverse of which is difficult to compute without specific information.

Most encryption is based on prime factorization. Alice multiplies two large prime numbers together, and gives the results to Bob. Bob uses this large prime number to encrypt his data using an encryption function. Finding the inverse of Bob's encryption function requires knowing the two original prime numbers (encryption does not). Finding these numbers is a very computationally expensive task, so the encrypted data is 'safe'.

Implementing this correctly is VERY difficult. If you want to keep data safe, find a library that does it for you.

EDIT: I should specify that what I described was public key encryption. Private key encryption works a bit differently. The important thing is that there's a mathematical basis for thinking that encrypted data will be hard to decrypt without a key or some sort.

Comment: overstood: which library would you suggest if you are given arbitrary ten-chars' ASCII passwords every week and you would not like to carry them on paper, instead use some sort of encryption and a secret key?

Comment: I might look at http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto/ EDIT: I just realized it doesn't support AES or Blowfish, which is probably what you want to be using. I'll post another one shortly.

Comment: Here's a great blog post on using PyCrypto to implement password based AES encryption: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto/

Comment: one time pad does not fit your definition of real encryption, yet it  certainly is _real_ encryption!

Comment: @gnibbler A one time pad still relies on a key for encryption and decryption. That aside, my point was that there's a mathematical basis for thinking that it's difficult (or impossible) to decrypt.